# "Il faut que jeunesse se passe"

Tags: expressions, traduction, proverbes

I was reading The Death of Ivan Ilyich of Lev Tolstoy when I read the expression "Il faut que jeunesse se passe". What does it mean? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is close to "boys will be boys", but just more gender-neutral.
It means that young people have a right to enjoy their youth, even if they disturb our upset older people sometimes, and that their elders should be tolerant and show some understanding for their behaviour or their mistakes.